Bjoern Error: symbol not found in flat namespace '_ev_cleanup_start'
I start work with legacy project and try run it on local machine.
I have M1 MacOS 14, Python3.8, bjoern==3.1.0.
In folder /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages there is file _bjoern.cpython-38-darwin.so
But I can't run project because I have error:
 from app.app import init_app
app/app.py:3: in <module>
    import bjoern
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bjoern.py:3: in <module>
    import _bjoern
E   ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_bjoern.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ev_cleanup_start'


I already tried delete all and then reinstall from zero and got same problem.
I tried different solution for bjoern:
brew install libev
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/opt/homebrew/include" --global-option="-L/opt/homebrew/lib" --target /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages bjoern==3.1.0 --no-cache-dir
But nothing helps.
What can I do with this ?

if it is "legacy project" then maybe it needs "legacy MacOS" ?

it seems there is source code in C/C++ https://github.com/jonashaag/bjoern/tree/master/bjoern - so maybe you should download it and compile
